# Display selected HTML table with Jquery (expectation vs reality)

Tags: jquery

HELPPPPP ME PEEPSS!

I have a jquery code which display selected html table row when clicked.

```
  $(document).ready(function (){
    $('table tbody').on("click", "tr", function() {
    alert($(this).text());
   });
   });
```

With this code i am able to get something like this
[image: reality]
what i am trying to achieve is when clicked on selected it will popup/display as shown below
[image: expectation]

Is anyone able to help me with this?

Comment: use modal or dialog box

Comment: it suppose to popup when click so it will be a dialog box@guradio

Comment: Inside the callback, you can use `$(this).find("td")` to select all the `td` elements in the row. You can then use `.each()` or `.eq()` to gather to content from that cell.

Comment: @Twisty ohhhhhh yaaaa thanks for the help really appreciate it

Comment: @Twisty do u have any idea if i need to display 2 element in the table?

Comment: @Twisty this is my code $(document).ready(function (){
        $('table tbody').on("click", "tr", function() {
  
        var value=$(this).find('td:eq(0)').html();
  
           alert(value);
      });
    });

Comment: @Twisty it okay i found out the solutiom